# Angular controller doesn't load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

I have a very simple Angular controller set up, but the code inside its constructor isn't running. Here are the relevant pieces:

conversationcontrollers.js:

```
var exampleApp = angular.module('exampleApp',[]);

console.log('file loaded');

exampleApp.controller('ConversationController', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
        console.log('controller constructor loads');
    }
]);
```

conversation.html:

```
...
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src='/static/js/conversationcontrollers.js'></script>
...
<div ng-controller="ConversationController">
</div>
...
```

The files both load correctly according to the browser. But the only results from the console are:

```
file loaded
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you have ng-app in your html element? What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Do you have `ng-app` declared in conversation.html?

Comment: show your full html, sounds likee your missing `ng-app`

Comment: Make sure you have in your html, proper html tag <html ng-app="exampleApp">

Comment: Another note, you are creating a new angular module with the `[]` parameter. If conversation.html is a partial loaded in `ng-view`, you may want to be using the parent angular module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll also need an ng-app. This tells angular which part of your page is the angular application.

```
<div ng-app="exampleApp" ng-controller="ConversationController">
</div>
```